# Nokogiri (Ruby) and XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath, nokogiri

Does Nokogiri only support XPath 1.0? I'm trying to do simple string replacement in a value-of cell, like so (where `element` contains something like '* My string (useless text)')

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(element,'^\*\ (.+)\ \(.*\)$','\\1')">
```

Is this poorly formed XSL? Or is there a limitation with Nokogiri?

Comment: If `replace()` does not work I would assume XSLT 2.0 is not supported. ;-) What is the string you try to replace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The [`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function is only defined in XPath 2.0 (and XPath 2.x is only supported by XSLT 2.x, not XSLT 1.0)**

Nokogiri uses [**libxml2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxml2), which only supports XPath 1.0/XSLT1.0

Comment: Is this still the case in 2014?

Comment: @marvin, It is still the same in respect to libxml. However, there is now Saxon/C, which is Saxon (for XPath 2/XSLT 2, translated to C). If the Nokogiri developers choose to use Saxon/C, this will provide support for XPath 2, and in the future, would probably provide support even for XPath 3. For more information, read this: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml

Comment: Any change? It's 2022 now...

Comment: @Sixtyfive AFAIK one can use Saxon/C with Python. Saxon/C implements XSLT 3.0 and can be used from any (mainly aiming at Linux) C applications and, I think also from Python